# How to compare dataframe values to numbers in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column 'Total Revenue' with numbers with decimals:

```
       Total Revenue 
0         100.96
1         48.694
```

I need to round up those numbers and have my Python script do some logic that compares those numbers to values of some variables. Once I generate the dataframe, I use the following code to round up numbers in that column:

```
df['Total Revenue'] = df['Total Revenue'].round(0).astype(int)
```

The result that I get is this:

```
       Total Revenue 
0         101
1          49
```

However, when I try to do the following to get values out of the dataframe and compare them to numbers, I get an error "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
totalRevenue = df.ix[[0], ['Total Revenue']]
if totalRevenue == 101:
    print "OK"
```

If I skip the rounding up step and start working with dataframe values like in the example below, I get an error "TypeError: a float is required".

```
totalRevenue = df.ix[[0], ['Total Revenue']]
totalRounded = math.ceil(totalRevenue * 1000.0) / 1000.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try if df['Total Revenue'].values[0] == 101: print ('ok')

Comment: `df.ix[[0], ['revenue']] == 101` returns a boolean dataframe (with a single column and a single row). if you try to use this as part of a condition, it is like calling `bool(<some dataframe>)` which returns the error you are seeing. Basically, `pandas` can't know what you expect the truth value of a DataFrame to be, so you have to be explicit, e.g. use `all`, `any`, etc. Or, in this case, change your indexing operation to return the value directly: `df.ix[0, 'Total Revenue']`

Answer (score 1):

by this `totalRevenue == 101`, you are essentially comparing a dataframe to a value, because [ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) always returns a dataframe, this comparison can be done by using `any()` or `all()` to determine if any or all values in the dataframe should by equal to the value

What you want to do is something the lines of

```
if totalRevenue.values == 101:
       print 'ok'
```

or

```
if any(totalRevenue == 101):
      print 'ok'
```